# Disable `redirect prefix` for `stats uri` in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

In HAProxy (1.5) I have this rule to redirect all requests to a canonical domain:

```
redirect prefix https://domain.tld code 301 unless { hdr(host) -i domain.tld }
```

This works fine. However, I also have stats enabled (`stats uri /haproxy-stats`). For these I would like to disable the redirect as I need to access specific haproxy machines (they are behind a DNS round-robin) through their own host name.

Is there any way of configuring HAProxy in such a way?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using an ACL rule:

```
acl url_stats path /haproxy-stats
redirect prefix https://domain.tld code 301 unless { hdr(host) -i domain.tld or url_stats }
```

Using an anonymous ACL works too:

```
redirect prefix https://domain.tld code 301 unless { hdr(host) -i domain.tld } || { path /haproxy-status }
```

---

However, it turned out to be not needed at all as HAProxy doesn't apply redirect rules to the stats url; probably I had an old 301 redirect cached.

Comment: Can you nest a named ACL inside an anonymous one?  I would have assumed `... unless { hdr(host) -i domain.tld } || url_stats` would be the syntax... although the named ACL could be dropped, and just use `... unless { hdr(host) -i domain.tld } || { path /haproxy-stats }`

Comment: Oh, didn't know about anonymous ACLs. good to know. I'll test it and update my answer accordingly

Comment: Testing is good.  For some reason, the docs sort of downplay the `{` `}` anonymous ACL construct, as though named ACLs are easier... but I find it much tidier unless there are several matching cases or the same condition is tested repeatedly (in which case, named ACLs are a good way to avoid forgetting to change the test everywhere it occurs).

Comment: Interesting, when testing again I noticed that even without this ACL I don't get a redirect. It seems like the redirects aren't applied to the stats at all. Maybe I had a cached 301 from before I had setup the stats.

Comment: I was going to ask about that :) but all of my stuff is 1.6+, so I thought that might explain it.  The stats hook is handled very early in request processing.